# Launchy::ApplicationNotFoundError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

Trying to get `save_and_open_page` to work at all gives me the following error:

```
1) index page my first test
 Failure/Error: save_and_open_page
 Launchy::ApplicationNotFoundError:
   No application found to handle 'C:/Sites/Sublist_v2/tmp/capybara/capybara-201304211638563116158687.html'
 # ./spec/features/comics_page_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'index page' do
  scenario "my first test" do
    visit root_path
    save_and_open_page
    # Launchy.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
  end
end
```

If I uncomment the Launchy line it works fine, so I'm not sure what the trouble is... maybe a problem with the path `c:/`?

`Gemfile`

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

Comment: interestingly I can however copy and paste the error message path into a browser and see the page.

Comment: I have the same problem. One thing I noticed is that when I copy the url and run it in commandline with `launchy C:/Sites/...` I get the same error, but when I put `file:///` before `C:`, it works.

Comment: Have the same issue. It was working before. Not sure if the error is related to running bundle update.

Comment: Perhaps [launchy #29](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/29#issuecomment-1617451) has come back?  What versions of capybara and launchy do you have installed. Are you using anything old (e.g. ruby < 1.9.3)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the drive letter in the file path is being incorrectly determined to be part of a uri scheme.

You can temporarily fix it by changing line 12 in /launchy/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb from:

`return true if File.exist?( uri.path ) and uri.scheme.nil?`

to

`return true if File.exist?( uri.path ) && !schemes.include?( uri.scheme )`

Comment: The solution has been verified and it works. Please mark it as answer so Brad can get bounty point. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I am the author of Launchy, and was just informed of this issue. I generally do bug fixes via GitHub and have put this issue there. [Issue #65](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/65)

Any time you encounter an issue with Launchy, please turn on launchy debugging and [file an issue with the project on github](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues)

You can can turn on launchy debugging by setting the environment variable `LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true`. You can do this either from the shell, or via ruby code if you are embedding launchy in your application.

```
% export LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true
% launchy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror
AUNCHY_DEBUG: URI parsing pass 1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror -> {:scheme=>"http", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :host=>"stackoverflow.com", :port=>nil, :path=>"/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror", :query=>nil, :fragment=>nil}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Application::Browser is the one for handles?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Windows is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Darwin is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::RubyEngine::Mri is the one for is_current_engine?(ruby)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Windows is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Darwin is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::RubyEngine::Mri is the one for is_current_engine?(ruby)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : found executable /usr/bin/open
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application::Browser : possibility : /usr/bin/open
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application::Browser : Using browser value '/usr/bin/open'
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: wet_run: before exec in child process
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: commandline_normalized => /usr/bin/open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror
```

Or if you are embedding launchy:

```
% irb
>> require 'launchy'
>> ENV['LAUNCHY_DEBUG']="true"
>> Launchy.open( "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror" )
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: URI parsing pass 1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror -> {:scheme=>"http", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :host=>"stackoverflow.com", :port=>nil, :path=>"/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror", :query=>nil, :fragment=>nil}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Application::Browser is the one for handles?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Windows is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Darwin is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::RubyEngine::Mri is the one for is_current_engine?(ruby)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Windows is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::HostOsFamily::Darwin is the one for matches?(darwin12.2.0)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Checking if class Launchy::Detect::RubyEngine::Mri is the one for is_current_engine?(ruby)}
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application : found executable /usr/bin/open
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application::Browser : possibility : /usr/bin/open
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: Launchy::Application::Browser : Using browser value '/usr/bin/open'
LAUNCHY_DEBUG: wet_run: before exec in child process
>> LAUNCHY_DEBUG: commandline_normalized => /usr/bin/open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137410/launchyapplicationnotfounderror
```

Comment: Also notice just now the save_and_open_page was not generating any error. But there was no page showing as well with rspec.

Comment: @copiousfreetime Can you please guide me on this issue,if launchy is not able to find any link let say there is a typo then is there any method available with launchy which allows it to search for the "word or link given"

Comment: @Abhinay Just making sure I understand what you are asking. You want Launchy to tell you if the url you pass to it is invalid, and what portion of it is invalid?

Comment: @copiousfreetime yeah partially but I was looking for some inbuilt function which will help it to do the same right now I am going this way which I feel is very lame but fine for me now, but yeah if you have any suggestions I am open to try it.here is the code http://pastebin.com/LK7jLj2V

Comment: @Abhinay I'm open to suggestions. Drop in here and leave some thoughts -- https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/89

Comment: @copiousfreetime One more thing, how can I handle which browser should Lanuchy be opening ?..I am unable to find a proper way to handle this..firefox is the default one but if there is something I can tweak on my own then that would be great.

Comment: @Abhinay If you set the `BROWSER` environment variable, Launchy will use it. See http://www.catb.org/esr/BROWSER/index.html for the appropriate use.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do:

```
fileUri = 'file:///' + outputFile.path

Launchy.open(fileUri)
```

note the three slashes after "file:". This is with github-markdown-0.5.5 on Windows 8.